# Facebook messenger bot- am not able to close the window on click of button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm navigating from messenger bot to url link("https://xyz.xyz.com/Facebook/apps/Facebook/common/views/Enquiryloans.html")
after opening this page in the browser i need to close this using `onclick`  javascript function. But i'm not able to close this page (error in the console is `:Enquiryloans.html:349`. Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.)

I tried:

```
{ window.open('', '_blank', ''); customWindow.close();}
```

But that window is not closing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the error message seems to be pretty clear, i am not sure what your question is?

Comment: btw, i removed the jquery tag, because there is no relation to jquery in this question. only use tags that are relevant.